# A surprising conjecture about twin primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, integer-sequences

Just for fun, I began to play with numbers of two distinct ciphers. I noticed that most of the cases if you consider the numbers $AB$ and $BA$ (written in base $10$), these have few common divisors: for example $13$ and $31$ are coprime, $47$ and $74$ are coprime. Obviously this is not always the case, because one can take non-coprime ciphers, however I realized that, for $0 \le a<b \le 9$, the quantity $$\gcd (10a+b, 10b+a)$$ is never too big. Using brute force I computed
$$\max \{ \gcd (10a+b, 10b+a) : 0 \le a<b \le 9\} = \gcd (48,84)=12$$

After that, I passed to an arbitrary base $n \ge 2$, and considered
$$f(n)= \max \{ \gcd (an+b, bn+a) : 0 \le a<b \le n-1 \}$$
For example $f(2)=1$ and $f(3)=2$.

Considering $n \ge 4$,
I noticed that, picking $a=2, b=n-3$ we have
$$2n+(n-3) = 3(n-1)$$
$$(n-3)n+2 = (n-2)(n-1)$$
so that $f(n)$ has a trivial lower bound
$$(n-1) \le \gcd (2n+(n-3), (n-3)n+2) \le f(n) $$
(which holds for $n=2,3$ as well).

A second remark is
$$\gcd (0n+b, bn+0) = b \le n-1$$
so that we can restrict ourselves to the case $a \neq 0$: in other words
$$f(n)=\max \{ \gcd (an+b, bn+a) : 1 \le a<b \le n-1 \}$$

I wrote a very simple program which computes the value of $f(n)$ for $n \le 400$, selecting those numbers such that $f(n)=n-1$. Surprisingly, I found out that many numbers appeared:
$$4, 6, 12, 18, 30, 42, 60, 72, 102, 108, 138, 150, 180, 192, 198, 228, 240, 270, 282, 312, 348$$

More surprisingly these turned out to be the numbers between couples of twin primes!
What is going on here?

Comment: 12 and 21 are not coprime.

Comment: @scaaahu At what point does the OP claim it is?

Comment: He said _in most of the cases_. The first one I consider breaks.

Comment: They never claim it always holds. They even give an example of $48,84$.

Comment: @Wojowu Yes, 24 and 42, 64 and 46, .. etc. too many. I cannot consider this is in most cases. See the first line of the question.

Comment: Actually, you are right. I ran a computation and 21 pairs are coprime, 24 pairs are not coprime. So the first line isn't really correct. This doesn't invalidate the question though.

Comment: @scaaahu Sometimes it helps to move past the first line of the question to the second line ("Obviously this is not always the case") or, if you're feeling bold, even the third line where OP considers the GCD of pairs.  Your comment is at best an irrelevant nitpick.

Comment: Any idea based on this property to show there should be infinitely many such numbers ?

Comment: Is your sequence in oeis.org yet?  If not, add it.  I'm sure Neil Sloane would like it.

Comment: @PatDevlin Yes, this sequence appears in OEIS. That's how I found that those numbers are indeed between twin primes.

Comment: Considering the large interest in this MO question, I thought it might be of interest for the reader and the OP to look into another amusing occurrence of the g.c.d. function plays a role in a prime generating function: [here is a paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL11/Rowland/rowland21.pdf) by Eric Rowland.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Suppose $n-1$ and $n+1$ are both primes.

$\gcd(an+b,bn+a)$ divides $an+b - (bn+a) = (a-b)(n-1)$.

There are two cases. If $n-1$ divides $\gcd(an+b,bn+a)$ then $b=n-1-a$ so $an+b= (n-1) (a+1)$ and $bn+a=(n-1)(b+1)$, so $\gcd(an+b,bn+a) = (n-1)\gcd(a+1,b+1)$.

$(a+1)+(b+1)=n+1$. Because $n+1$ is prime, two numbers that sum to it must be relatively prime (any common prime factor would be a prime factor of $n+1$, so woul be $n+1$, but $a+1$ and $b+1$ are both less than $n+1$.) So in this case $\gcd(an+b,bn+a) = n-1$.

On the other hand, because $n-1$ is prime, if $n-1$ does not divide $\gcd(an+b,bn+a)$ then $\gcd(an+b,bn+a)$ divides $a-b$ and so is at most $n-2$.

So in this case the maximum value is $n-1$, attained whenever $a+b=n-1$.

If $n+1$ is not prime you can get greater than $n-1$ in the first case by taking a prime $\ell$ dividing $n+1$, setting $a=\ell-1$, $b=n-\ell$ for a gcd of $\ell (n-1)$.

If $n-1$ is not prime but instead $n-1= cd$ with $c \leq d$, you can set $a=d+1$, $b=(c-1)(d+1) \leq cd <n$ so that $an+b= (d+1) (cd+1) + (c-1)(d+1) = c d^2 +2cd + c= c(d+1)^2$ and $(b-a)(n-1)=(c-2) (d+1) cd$ are both divisible by $c (d+1) > n-1$, so the gcd is divisible by $c(d+1)$ and hence greater than $n-1$.